# Android soft keyboard partially overlapping views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard, tablet, android-4.4-kitkat

I am using `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"` to adjust keyboard on screen. It is not working in Tablets with OS 4.4 but it is working fine in Mobile devices. Below I am attaching image.
[image]

Here is my `layout`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_main"
    android:id="@+id/parentCanvas">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_edit_screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/toolbarTransparent"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/setting_button"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        ></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="414.75dp"
        android:layout_height="233.25dp"
        android:id="@+id/parentCanvas1"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_edit_screen"
        android:layout_marginTop="10.00dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10.00dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="414.75dp"
            android:layout_height="233.25dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            />
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBarMainImage"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutButtons"
        android:layout_width="64.00dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_edit_screen"
        android:paddingLeft="10.00dp"
        android:paddingRight="10.00dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/parentCanvas1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/parentCanvas1"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/parentCanvas1"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_ic__add"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:paddingTop="19dp"
            android:paddingBottom="19dp"
            android:paddingLeft="19dp"
            android:paddingRight="19dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonCopy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/buttonAdd"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_dup"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingTop="19dp"
            android:paddingBottom="19dp"
            android:paddingLeft="19dp"
            android:paddingRight="19dp"


            />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonSlideShow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/buttonCopy"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_play"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingTop="19dp"
            android:paddingBottom="19dp"
            android:paddingLeft="19dp"
            android:paddingRight="19dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonRemove"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/buttonSlideShow"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingTop="19dp"
            android:paddingBottom="19dp"
            android:paddingLeft="19dp"
            android:paddingRight="19dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/selectImag"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/buttonRemove"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_imgimport"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="19dp"
            android:paddingLeft="19dp"
            android:paddingRight="19dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/straightLine"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/relativeLayoutButtons"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_edit_screen"
        />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutCircleDropdown"
        android:layout_width="414.75dp"
        android:layout_height="200px"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/parentCanvas1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/parentCanvas1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/parentCanvas1">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/drawCircle"
            android:layout_width="50.75dp"
            android:layout_height="50.75dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/circle_img"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginRight="6.75dp"/>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_small_line"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="35.50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/drawCircle"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7.00dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="7.00dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_marginTop="8.00dp"
            />
        <ssi.sarissa.views.EditTextWithBackEvent
            android:id="@+id/editTextDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/view_small_line"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxLength="160"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="3.00dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:hint="Description"
            />
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/editTextDescription"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutList"
        android:layout_width="158.50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_edit_screen"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/straightLine"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/relativeLayoutButtons"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't know where I am getting wrong.

Comment: Is your activity a full screen activity ?

Comment: No. I am using toolbar.

Comment: Did u try adjustPan ?

Comment: Yes. I have tried adjustPan, stateAlwaysHidden. But no one is working.

Comment: can you put the layout for this?

Comment: Try `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in the root layout.

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal I have tried, but did't work.

Comment: try wrapping your layout with scrollview as mentioned in this link https://www.davidwparker.com/2011/08/25/android-fixing-window-resize-and-scrolling/

Comment: @UmarQureshi I have tried it already..